# View Width when camera.setlens is used

Tags: three.js

I know the formula to calculate view width and height.

```
var vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180;        // convert vertical fov to radians
var height = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 ) * dist; // visible height

var aspect = window.width / window.height;
var width = height * aspect;
```

But when `camera.setlens(60)` is involved calculations are going wrong. Will the formula changes when we use `Camera.setlens` .

Comment: Did you look at the soure code to see what `setLens()` does? http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look at the docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera) or [the source](http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js)

`Camera.setLens` does not take a field of view. It takes focal length and a frame size

Comment: so fov will be THREE.Math.radToDeg(Math.atan(frameHeight / (focalLength * 2)));